# Can TFS use both Git and TFVC on the same repo

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc

I'm working on a big Web solution that uses TFS 2015 as source code management along with TFVC.

There is one scientific project, will generate a bunch of JavaScript files, needs to be accessed by another team that uses Git.

Can TFS have a single repository managed by both Git and TFVC so both teams can work on it simultaneously?

Comment: What's the detail version of your TFS2015? RTM or update x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible for now.

However as a workaround, you could use Git and TFVC repos **in the same team project.**

> In Team Foundation Server 2015 **Update 1** and above, a project
>   administrator can add a Git repo to a team project created with Team
>   Foundation Version Control (TFVC).
>
> This allows you to adopt a new version control system while preserving
>   all the data in your team project.

More details please refer this tutorial: [TFVC and Git repositories in the same team project](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/12/03/tfvc-and-git-repositories-in-the-same-team-project/)

Or you could also use  a **two-way bridge** between TFS (Team Foundation Server) and git, similar to git-svn. It fetches TFS commits into a git repository, and lets you push your updates back to TFS. Such as [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs).

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible.

You could use a tool like [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) as a bridge.
That's still better than TFVC for most of the actions but don't solve every problems...